# function name from thread id in Xcode objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My code is getting crashed due to queue

I am getting the thread id so is there any way to get the function name from the thread id in objective-c? i don't know where the code is getting crashed. i have used different kinds of exceptions and breakpoints some lldb command but it doesn't show me the function name or the class which is creating issue. can anyone suggest me thanks for the help.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9zk4.png)

```
<NSThread: 0x7b1000077880>{number = 17, name = (null)}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for a good quality question, then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: i am using dispatch in many places but idk which is causing crash like 1000 of dispatch @MubinMall